# In WordPress, I am trying to configure TinyMCE so styles are treated as inline spans

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using inline styles in spans because I am making an email CMS which means certain elements need to be styled inline so they will be universally read across email clients. What I encounter with Wordpress is bold injects `<strong>` italic `<em>` however underline injects `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">`

I want to be able to use span and the appropriate inline style property. The version of Wordpress I am using is bundled with tinymce, a wysiwyg editor. I read a little bit about overriding the formats for tinymce [TinyMCE Formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aformats)

It looks like much of the tinyMCE is defined in this PHP include

```
/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php
```

I am still not sure how to go about overriding the definitions. I was thinking there ought to be a way of overriding them in my theme's functions.php

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Codex has [a whole page on TinyMCE Custom Styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles), including code samples that should help get you started. You might also want to look at [add_editor_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) to register a custom editor stylesheet to apply some of the styles within the editor window itself.